# How iAd searches for content to display?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I have an iPhone app that implements iAd. In debugging mode everything works fine and I'm showing the test advertisement correctly on simulator and on device with no particular logs or errors.

The app was approved and it's in the app store, but is not showing any ad.

I show the iAd in a UIview with lots of textual content, but in Italian (don't know if language matters, btw the app is available in all the app stores).

I wonder how iAd search for content and then displays related banners and how I can somehow "force" content by passing (if possible) tags or predefined content.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you configure iAd through the iAd portal in iTunes Connect? Also, what category is your app?

Comment: You could have a look at https://iad.apple.com/itcportal/ and have a look at the stats for your app. It'll tell you the requests it's made, for different countries, as well as fill rates. This might help you understand if the app is making requests but there are just no ads available.

Comment: I'll check and update the question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply forgot to add my app to the iAd service.
I needed to upload a new version in order to fix this.

Let's wait for apple approval.

Thanks!